# Is there a function that returns the changes between two matrices4x4 in glm

Tags: c++, glm-math

I need to find the changes that happened between two time t1 and t2 and i have the `glm::mat4` for both of them (m1 , m2) I am currently using the following code (which doesn't work):

```
glm::mat4 changes ( const glm::mat4& m1 , const glm::mat4& m2 ){
    return m1 / m2 ;
}
```

Comment: Can you describe in more details the error that you have (compilation, execution)? I see an operator for matrix division in the glm API.

Comment: It's an execution error

Comment: Please provide more details in the question: What is the result and what are you expecting as a result?

Comment: The 'operator /' returns "m1 * glm::inverse(m2)", which is not the element-wise division. If element-wise division is what you are looking for, you will have to code it by hand. On the other hand, does a simple matrix subtraction could be what you really want? Depending on what you mean by "find the changes", it could even be more appropriate than division, which has potential for division-by-zero.

Comment: I have a physics engine that has a glm::mat4 ( rigid body ) i need to synchronise the glm::mat4 of my object and my rigidbody so i need to be able to get the differences of the glm::mat4 of my object so as to modify the glm::mat4 of my rigidbody

Comment: If you want to test for a change, I suggest to use subtraction. If you want to synchronize your object with the rigid body, why not just affecting the new matrix to the object every frame?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok after my research i found a solution ,I use `glm::decompose` and then I manage the data the way i want to get the previus result .